# org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase : A child container failed during start

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, google-drive-api, jetty

My problem seems like others but I have tried other solutions and nothing works so I am putting here, I am using spring boot and need to integrate google drive to download files, following three dependencies need to be added as per google documentation.

```
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    //compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev94-1.23.0'
```

Both my application and google sample working fine independently, however When I include the above dependencies in my project `build.gradle` the commented out dependency causes the following exception and applcation failed to start.

```
2017-12-25 01:09:26.593[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12741[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36ms.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8088 (http)
[2m2017-12-25 01:09:26.639[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12741[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2017-12-25 01:09:26.641[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12741[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
[2m2017-12-25 01:09:26.871[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m12741[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[cat-startStop-1][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5117) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:182) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

I am using **STS** that uses tomcat container,so is there any thing messy with tomcat and jetty???

Comment: Have you looked at the dependency tree to determine if there are any conflicting packages or if com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty is overriding anything?

Comment: Tomcat 8.5 supports servlet spec 3.1, so `javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName` should be present. If you have somehow replaced the `servlet-api.jar` file with one that is from a prior version of the servlet spec, you will likely get an error of this type.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz thank you sir,I actually didnt added but that jetty dependency addind that, so my problem is resolved by adding servlet3.1.0 version to my gradle,

Comment: @SeanCarroll yes i checked the tree and nothing overiding i mean the only servlet-api2.0 was present and that is from jetty , I also tried with transitive dependency setting false ,but no luck

Comment: I created a sample project using spring boot 1.5.9 (tomcat 8.5.23) and added the 3 dependencies listed I was able to successfully boot up the application. The version of servlet-api from jetty (6.1.26) I see is 2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few solution I tried by getting help from SO were

- adding transitive dependencies false for the jetty (one that is
  causing trouble) but nothing happens
- tried with servlet api 3.0.1 but no luck

**solution that works is by adding servlet api 3.1.0 to my `build.gradle`**